# Can I know who tried to login to my Google account?

Tags: authentication, google, geolocation

I recevied a notification that someone tried to access my Google account and it was denied, so i quickly changed the password. Google tells me the IP number in the notification and a location. I wonder if I can know the specific location or who it might have been (their social media or any other type of information)?

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no way for you to know who it was. Might not even be a person, could just as well be a hacked computer that is part of a botnet trying to brute force random accounts.

The IP could tell you what ISP the person uses, and a vague geographic location that is not very precise. But that is only if who ever it was didn't use a VPN, Tor or some kind of proxy. So in practice even that info might be wrong.

Really, I wouldn't care to much about this. Make sure you have a strong password that you don't reuse and turn on two factor authentication. Stopping people from gaining access to your accounts is a much better strategy than trying to track down those who tried.

Comment: And if you were to somehow succeed in tracking this person down, what would you do?